# How to instert full citation, instead of citation key? List of Author's publication?

Tags: bibliographies

I'm using multibib to typeset two "bibliographies": references and bibliographies. My supervisors don't want any keys/number in the text nor in the bibliographies section. I'm using `\nocite{key}` to suppress the key appearance in the text, but this still generates citations keys in the bibliography section. How do I simply insert full citation without a key (inverse of what is printed by the `\cite`)?

**Example**

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.[1] Vivamus urna nisi, mattis eget convallis eget, sollicitudin eget quam. Duis lobortis odio vitae nulla vestibulum id suscipit ante elementum. Nulla vitae justo nec risus vehicula commodo.[2] Aenean commodo diam eget mi tincidunt condimentum. Nunc dolor nibh, mollis in vehicula auctor, porta aliquam lorem. Ut sagittis ipsum vel lorem sagittis sed bibendum ipsum molesti

**References**
[1] *Citation*
[2] *Citation*

**Bibliography**
*Citation*
*Citation* - This one is best to read last.

Comment: I see, much clearer now. I've updated my answer to address your actual problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use whatever bibliography style you're currently using to `\cite` and render your references section. Then use the `bibentry` package to generate your bibliography section.

Comment: I needed numbered style for the "references", but no keys in text and no keys in the style for the "bibliography"

Comment: Couldn't believe my eyes =) this is exactly what I need!

Comment: I'm glad it helped :D

Answer (score 2):

I expect that there's a package that would do it better, and I second the suggestion to check `natbib`.  However, if nothing turns up, here's a hack that does it.  I copied the definition of the `thebibliography` environment from `article.cls` and removed the bit where it prints a label (the empty first argument to the `\list{}%` line).  With two bibliographies, you will probably want to keep the original bibliography environment as well so you should give this one a unique name.  If you're using the `\bibliography` command to import the bibliographies rather than specifying them in the document then you will need to hack one of them to use the new command rather than the original one (unless the `multibib` thing that you mention does this automatically).

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\section*{\refname}%
      \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
      \list{}%
           {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
            \leftmargin\labelwidth
            \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
            \@openbib@code
            \usecounter{enumiv}%
            \let\p@enumiv\@empty
            \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
      \sloppy
      \clubpenalty4000
      \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
      \widowpenalty4000%
      \sfcode`\.\@m}
     {\def\@noitemerr
       {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
      \endlist}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{thebibliography}{KPMS82}

\bibitem{bm}
Michael Barr.
\newblock Coalgebras over a commutative ring.
\newblock {\em J. Algebra}, 32(3):600--610, 1974.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: woow.. sorry but this is ugly, ugly, ugly. Why do this if other packages already do the work for you?

Comment: Hmmmm... Looks good but I would prefer if it was a BibTeX style based on IEEEtrans. I know, I'm asking too much =)

Comment: @Juan A. Navarro: Ugly is in the eye of the beer holder!  I could counter with: Why use a package if it's just a minor hack?  The package that does this might be huge and load lots of extra code which isn't necessary (imagine using TikZ just to draw a horizontal line).  Plus, by seeing how it might be done in "raw" code, someone might get the "TeX bug" and turn from TeX user to TeX hacker!  But I do have some sympathy with your position and note my "get out" clause at the beginning.

Comment: @Dima: I'd need to test to be sure, but this should be independent of BibTeX style since it modifies the bibliography _environment_, not the style of the BibTeX entries.  Try it!

Comment: I get that. But that's the point that references will look different from bibliography. I want both of them use same bibtex styles (e.g. change on the fly).

Comment: @Dima: I don't understand.  This ought to simply remove the index from the style whatever the style is so both the old and the new will look the same, apart from the indexing.  So changing BibTeX styles should work as you want.  (As you say that Juan's answer does exactly what you want, I'm not going to do any further testing!)

Comment: @Andrew Stacey: Right let me try this in my thesis.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [here](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/90477737a2563a33/e9c7ceaf62e2adcf)

On Mar 23 2009, 12:44 pm, Christian Riesch  wrote:

> I got very helpful replies, especially from Michael Shell. I used this code:
>   \documentclass{article}
>   \usepackage{multibib}
>   \newcites{apubs}{AuthorPublications}
>
> \begin{document}
>   \cite{pub1,pub2,pub3}
>   \nociteapubs{apub1,apub2}
>
> % authorpublications
>   \begingroup
>   \labelsep 0pt % set left indentation
>   \makeatletter
>   \def\@biblabel#1{\relax} % turn off biblabels
>   \makeatother
>   \bibliographystyleapubs{IEEEtran}
>   \bibliographyapubs{mybibfile}
>   \endgroup
>
> % "global" bibliography
>   \begingroup
>   \continuouslabelsfalse
>   \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
>   \bibliography{mybibfile}
>   \endgroup
>
> \end{document}

Comment: link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `jurabib` packages/bibstyle together with `\nocite` for the "bibliography" bibliography provides what you want?

Comment: I looked trough jurabib. It looks good, but not for my field. I'm using IEEEtrans style for engineering reference style.