# Pop-up references in PDF output

Tags: pdftex, bibliographies, hyperref

I once saw a maths journal which offered PDFs of published papers, where the bibliographic references were formatted as PDF annotations: if you moused over a reference in the text, the bibliography entry would appear in a pop-up window, without having to jump to the end of the file and inevitably have to spend ages re-finding where you were in the text.

Does anyone know of a way of producing this effect automatically using BibTeX?

Comment: For what it's worth, the journal is Compositio Mathematica -- those with an institutional subscription can download PDFs at http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayJournal?jid=COM.

Comment: Commenting here for visibility: some good answers to this question have been given as answers to the newer question, [Showing the bibliographic entry in a popup…](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15356/showing-the-bibliographic-entry-in-a-popup-when-you-hover-over-the-citation-key)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Pop-up annotations can be made using the [`pdfcomment` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcomment), but I haven't seen an automatic way yet. But you could redefine a cite macro to use, for instance, `\pdfmarkupcomment` for the output.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; I've seen pdfcomment before, but I'm nowhere near competent enough with hacking LaTeX internals to know how to redefine \cite properly.

Comment: @David Loeffler: I don't know how to view pdf pop-ups so I can't test the syntax, but if you can figure out from the pdfcomment documentation what exactly you want to do then redefining the `\cite` command is easy: `\let\oldcite\cite \renewcommand{\cite}[1]{\pdfcomment{whatever the right syntax is}\oldcite{#1}}`.  Use `#` inside the `\pdfcomment` bit to get the label.  (Note: this doesn't do quite everything because you'd need to load the bibliography entry in to that argument.  That's a little more complicated.)

Comment: As I just learned (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/815/how-to-instert-full-citation-instead-of-citation-key-list-of-authors-publicati) you can get the bibliography entry with the `bibentry` package.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent suggestion of using pdfcomment and bibentry; but I'm struggling to get this to work. Just redefining \cite to \pdfcomment{\bibentry{#1}}\oldcite{#1} produces errors by the thousand and corrupted output, because the output of bibentry contains LaTeX commands that aren't valid in a PDF comment.

Comment: See recent related (might be duplicate) posts. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84681/interactive-pdf-latex-and-article-of-the-future/85910#85910, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82336/mouseover-events-in-beamer-hovering-on-eqref-and-a-comment-containing-the-orig

Comment: Reading through all the linked stuff, it seems that all those `pdfannot`, and `pdfcomment`, and `fancy-preview` solutions require Acrobat Reader, right?

Answer (score 11):

Non-answers that help even if you don't have the source code available:

- Some PDF viewers display hyperlink popups automatically; at least [Skim.app](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/) does that. You don't need to do anything in Latex; just use hyperref as usual and open the document in Skim.
- Most modern PDF viewers have a "back" button, just like a web browser. For example, if you click a hyperlink in Preview.app (built-in PDF viewer in Mac OS X), you can go back to where you were by pressing cmd-[.

Comment: +1 for the non-answer. I was wondering how I got this effect without using anything special, and it was just Skim doing the right thing.

Answer (score 5):

You can use fancy preview:

[Showing the bibliographic entry in a popup when you hover over the citation key](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15356/showing-the-bibliographic-entry-in-a-popup-when-you-hover-over-the-citation-key)

And refer to the following webiste for the details and requirements

http://user.mendelu.cz/marik/fancy-preview/

(I would've put this in a comment but I don't have enough reputation)

Answer (score 3):

There is [cooltooltips](http://ctan.org/pkg/cooltooltips) package that does what you need..

Comment: Is it possible to demo with a simple example, in this way it might add value to the post.

Comment: Even cooler, because the pop-ups are TeX formatted: ["Interactive PDF, Latex and Article of the Future" with opentype/truetype fonts and unicode](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111932)

Comment: Is there a PDF viewer for Linux that supports this? The PDF doc of cooltooltips fails to render the demo pop-up in Evince, Okular, and qpdfview.