# How to show the detail of cite bibitem by a framebox?

Tags: bibliographies

Recently， an editor want to get the result as follow:
http://cpl.iphy.ac.cn/qikan/public/pdfdow_en.asp?xiazailx=%C3%E2%B7%D1&bsid=11963&ag=0&gaohao=2010-1162&houzhui=.pdf

In the pdf document every cite hyperlink can show the detail of bib.
I want to know how to do?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the [pdfcomment](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcomment) package is what you are looking for? It seems you can't just put a `\pdfmarkupcomment[opacity=0]{\cite{key}}{note}` though, when using `hyperref`. The hyperlink itself will not be annotated then.

You might want to look [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/872/pop-up-references-in-pdf-output) as well.