# Showing the bibliography in popup on mouseover

Tags: pdf, citing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Showing the bibliographic entry in a popup when you hover over the citation key](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15356/showing-the-bibliographic-entry-in-a-popup-when-you-hover-over-the-citation-key)

Recently, I read a paper published in the [Compositio Mathematica](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayJournal?jid=COM) journal and found a very interesting feature. When I move my mouse over a link which links to a reference, I get detail of the reference showing as a popup window in yellow. I'm interested in knowing how one can do that.

Comment: Perhaps the answer to this question could be useful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15356/3954

Comment: We have a bingo; that is a perfect implementation of what I am also looking for! Now if we could only reverse engineer their code...