# Bibliography tooltips with XeLaTeX and automated workflow

Tags: bibliographies, biblatex, xetex, pdf, workflow

I would like to make bibliographic entries appear in a popup tooltips (in a supporting PDF viewer) when you hover over the citation key.

An approach to realise this was discussed here: [Showing the bibliographic entry in a popup when you hover over the citation key](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15356/3800)

However, I was wondering if it would be possible to make this work in XeLaTex (which according to the comments is not possible now) and to automate the proposed workflow (i.e. this is *not* a duplicate question).

In the proposed solution the tooltips for cited works must be generated in a separate pdf, compiled from a manually assembled tex file. I was wondering if this could be automated by generating this secondary tex file upon compilation of the main file (i.e. generating the tooltip contents for every entry that is cited in the main document). After which the tooltips are inserted in a second compilation run.

Based on what was proposed I was thinking of something like this:

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[createtips]{fancytooltips}
\usepackage[filename=bibtips,mouseover]{fancytooltips}

\newcommand\MyTip[1]{%
  \keytip{#1}
  \fcolorbox{green!50!black}{yellow!20}{\parbox{\textwidth}{\fullcite{#1}}}\newpage%
}

\let\cite\oldcite
\renewcommand\cite[1]{
%add \MyTip{#1} to bibtips.tex, to be compiled separately
\tooltip{\oldcite{#1}}{#1} %will resolve tooltip contents from bibtips.pdf in 2nd run
}
```