# Possible incompatibility between biblatex and hyperref's pdfmark?

Tags: biblatex, hyperref, pdf

I am trying to use `biblatex`'s `\citetitle` inside a `\pdfmark` so that the title of a citation pops up as a tooltip in PDFs.

Code looks like this:

```
%% A tooltip macro using pdfmark

\newcounter{tooltip}
% Creates a tooltip text.
%  arg #1 : the text to display
%  arg #2 : the text to show in the tooltip
\newcommand\tooltip[2]{%
  \pdfmark[#1]{%
    pdfmark=/ANN,%
    Subtype=/Widget,%
    Raw={%
      /TU (#2)/T (tooltip \thetooltip)%
      /FT/Btn/Ff 65536/H/N%
    }%
  }\protect\addtocounter{tooltip}{1}%
}
```

Now I can use the tooltip macro with regular text and with commands I create, for example:

```
% will show "some text" with "tooltip text" as tooltip on mouseover
\tooltip{some text}{tooltip text} 

% will show "Tooltip tooltip" as tooltip
\newcommand{\test}[1]{Tooltip #1}
\tooltip{some text}{\test{tooltip}}
```

However, if I use `\citetitle`, it does not expand:

```
% will show "\citetitle{key}" as tooltip
\tooltip{some text}{\citetitle{key}}
```

I tried adding some `\expandafter` at some places to no avail.

Also, inside my tooltip macro `\citetitle` gets expanded (e.g., if I use `#2` outside `\pdfmark`). It seems that only inside the RAW  argument it does not get expanded. On the other hand, my simple command gets expanded also in the RAW.

Since I do not know much about TeX, I was not able to debug the problem further, but it seems like some incompatibility between RAW and the way `biblatex` defines its macros. Any help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `/TU` argument of `Raw` expects unformatted text. Any citation command is devised to format bibliographic data, so the problem isn't really an issue with biblatex. You can access unformatted data using the biblatex commands `\thefield`, `\thename` and `\thelist`. The latter two  return name and literal list fields, respectively. Unfortunately they don't give output suitable for printing.

Below we define the citation commands `\tooltipcitefield` and `\tooltipcitename`, which make use of `\thefield` and `\thename`. These macros have three arguments to specify the display text, field name and entry keys. If the specified field isn't `labelnumber`, the fields are prefixed with the label number wrapped in brackets.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}
\usepackage[dvips]{hyperref}

\newcounter{tooltip}
\newcommand*{\tooltip}[2]{%
  \pdfmark[#1]{
    pdfmark=/ANN,Subtype=/Widget,
    Raw={/TU (#2 )                % annotation text
         /T (tooltip \thetooltip) % annotation title
         /FT /Btn                 % button field
         /Ff 65536                % push button field flag
         /H /N                    % no highlighting
    }
  }%
  \stepcounter{tooltip}}

\makeatletter

\newrobustcmd*{\cbx@displaytext}{}

\newrobustcmd*{\mkbibtooltip}[1]{%
  #1\cbx@displaytext%
  \settowidth{\@tempdima}{\cbx@displaytext}%
  \nobreak\hskip-\@tempdima%
  \tooltip{\hskip\@tempdima}{\csuse{cbx@tooltiptext}}%
  \csgdef{cbx@tooltiptext}{}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@tooltipcitefield}[\mkbibtooltip]
  {\iffieldundef{prenote}{}{\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}}
  {\ifcsstring{cbx@field}{labelnumber}
     {}
     {\csxappto{cbx@tooltiptext}{[\thefield{labelnumber}] }}%
   \csxappto{cbx@tooltiptext}{\thefield{\csuse{cbx@field}}}}
  {\csgappto{cbx@tooltiptext}{; }}
  {\iffieldundef{postnote}{}{\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}

\newrobustcmd*{\tooltipcitefield}[2]{%
  \renewrobustcmd*{\cbx@displaytext}{#1}%
  \csgdef{cbx@field}{#2}%
  \cbx@tooltipcitefield}

\DeclareIndexNameFormat{thename}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststart}}
    {\ifboolexpr{ test {\ifnumless{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
                  or test \ifmorenames }
      {\csgappto{cbx@tooltiptext}{, }}
      {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\csgappto{cbx@tooltiptext}{,}}{}%
       \csgappto{cbx@tooltiptext}{ and }}}
    {}%
  \ifuseprefix{\ifblank{#5}{}{\csgappto{cbx@tooltiptext}{#5 }}}{}%
  \csgappto{cbx@tooltiptext}{#1}%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\ifnumequal{\value{listcount}}{\value{liststop}}}
               and test \ifmorenames }
    {\ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{1}{\csgappto{cbx@tooltiptext}{,}}{}%
     \csgappto{cbx@tooltiptext}{ et al.}}
    {}}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\cbx@tooltipcitename}[\mkbibtooltip]
  {\iffieldundef{prenote}{}{\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}}
  {\csxappto{cbx@tooltiptext}{[\thefield{labelnumber}] }%
   \indexnames[thename]{\csuse{cbx@name}}}
  {\csgappto{cbx@tooltiptext}{; }}
  {\iffieldundef{postnote}{}{\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}

\newrobustcmd*{\tooltipcitename}[2]{%
  \renewrobustcmd*{\cbx@displaytext}{#1}%
  \csgdef{cbx@name}{#2}%
  \cbx@tooltipcitename}

\makeatother

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
Filler text \tooltipcitefield{\cite[e.g.][]{bertram,cicero}}{labeltitle}{bertram,cicero}.
Filler text \tooltipcitename{\cites[10--15]{bertram}[10]{cicero}}{labelname}{bertram,cicero}.
\tooltipcitefield{Tooltip titles}{labeltitle}{bertram,companion,cicero}.
\tooltipcitename{Tooltip names}{labelname}{companion,bertram,vangennep}.
\tooltipcitefield{\emph{Tooltip numbers}}{}{cicero,companion}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Here's an image of the document taken from Adobe Reader after compiling with `latex`, `bibtex`, `dvips` and `ps2pdf`.

[image]

This solution has a few open problems.

- Linebreaks. When the display text breaks across a line, the tooltip is applied only to the text after the linebreak. See the above document for an example.
- Hyperlinks and tooltips. These don't combine well. As a workaround the citation commands apply the tooltip to the baseline of the display text. This area is about 3pt high. It can be made higher and be displayed on mouse rollover. Some details on the `\pdfmark` options can be found on [D.P. Story's page](http://www.math.uakron.edu/~dpstory/lnk_forms.html).
- Citations as display text. With the existing commands you have to specify the entry keys twice. Moreover the tooltip area includes pre- and postnotes and only one tooltip is assigned to citation lists. All of these problems probably can't be addressed with the workaround described above.

Comment: Thanks Audrey, that works exactly like I asked!

Just forgot to add something to the question, perhaps you can help. If I do `\tooltipcite{\cite{ctan}}{labeltitle}{ctan}` then I get the tooltip, but the hyperref link does not work in the pdf. Is there a simple workaround?

Comment: @ttonelli I think so, but I'll need to take a look.

Comment: Thanks! I should note that I am also using `dvips` and `ps2pdf`. Using Okular I can see tooltips in the dvi, unless the base text is \cite{} (then the tooltip says "go to page X"); in the pdf I cannot see the tooltips. Now, in Acrobat Reader (which is my goal), I can see the tooltip always, even if I use \cite{} for the base text. But then, the link does not work in Acrobat...

Comment: @ttonelli The links work, but you have to click outside the tooltip area, toward the top of the link box. This isn't very user-friendly. The issue has been discussed at [comp.text.tex](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/browse_thread/thread/21e48da2673fec40). I think a workaround could be found if tooltip area can be made smaller. I'll look into this and make an edit to this answer when I find some time. If it's any consolation, I found a nice way to format name lists. So the edit will at least give you that.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that I can follow the link by positioning the mouse at the top. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: thanks again, the last edit seems like a very good compromise, given what PDF allows. The only problem I found is that the first time I use latex I get an error ( Argument of \@settodim has an extra } ), I think because there are no bib entries generated by bibtex yet. But since I cannot run bibtex without a .aux, there's a deadlock. My solution is to run latex and bibtex without checking their result (in a Makefile). That is, I run `-latex -draftmode --interaction=nonstopmode file.tex` and then `-bibtex file`. The - in front of the commands tells make to ignore the result.

Comment: @ttonelli I'm getting taken to school on this problem. `\settowidth` is robust so it won't take any fragile arguments, even if they are protected. The `\tooltipcite` variants protect the display text command. This is necessary on the first run. I'll ditch these citation commands in another edit. Regarding the "compromise", your limitation is the driver. Life is [much easier with `pdflatex`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15356/4483). The workflow described in that post is cumbersome, but it is easy to improve.

Comment: I hope you like school! Sorry for the complications, I thought things would be simpler. BTW, I liked your old `\tooltipcite` variants so I will keep them, even if I need a workaround on the first run. I tried to use fancytooltips before, but didn't like the way tooltips looked like (I bet there are config options to fix that, but I didn't look much). Anyway, thanks a lot for the help, I wish I could give you more points!

Comment: @ttonelli No need to apologize - I should've known better. Edit histories on posts are saved, so you can access the old citation commands from the previous edit. Messing around with fancytooltips options definitely seems simpler at this point. Keep tabs on that question I linked. I might get around to posting an alternative for you there.