# How can I get fancy-preview to work?

Tags: preview, fancytooltips

I would like to add `fancy-preview` to a document that I have created. I thought it would be best to get to learn how to use it on a simple example, so I found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15356/showing-the-bibliographic-entry-in-a-popup-when-you-hover-over-the-citation-key/54831#comment165111_54831) TeX.SE question. I then tried to work with the example document that was given by robert.marik.cz. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\usepackage{hyperref} % Important!
\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}[Lemma from \cite{M}]\label{lemma}
If $k<0$, then
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1}
x^2+k<x^2
\end{equation}
for every real number $x$.
\end{lemma}

Inequality \eqref{eq:1} in Lema \ref{lemma} can be proved easily. Is
more general than \cite[Theorem 3.4]{K}.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem[M]{M} Me: My book related to the problem (2006), 145 p.
% The new line is important!

\bibitem{K} Karl: Karl's paper published in some minor proceedings, 
a local conferrence organized by his university (2005), 23--25.
% The new line is important!


\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

I compiled the document with no errors (or modifications to the code) but the PDF (in Adobe Reader) does not give the desired effect. Specifically, the previews do not show.

Comment: You need the `fancy-preview` script that robert.marik.cz made. You can download the script here: http://user.mendelu.cz/marik/fancy-preview/

Comment: Shameless advertisement: there is a new question that I answered that also answered your question. I totally forgot about your question. :) Here it is: [Mouseover events in beamer: hovering on \eqref and a comment containing the original equation popping up](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82336/mouseover-events-in-beamer-hovering-on-eqref-and-a-comment-containing-the-orig/82352#82352)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `fancy-preview` script as I have mentioned in my comment. Follow the guide in my answer to [Mouseover events in beamer: hovering on \eqref and a comment containing the original equation popping up](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82336/mouseover-events-in-beamer-hovering-on-eqref-and-a-comment-containing-the-orig/82352#82352).

Then in your terminal, run the command:

```
perl fancy-preview myfile
```

without the file extension.