# Mouseover events in beamer: hovering on \eqref and a comment containing the original equation popping up

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, hyperref, comments, fancytooltips

This idea came into my mind while I was listening to a speaker presenting his results in a seminar, he used lots of equation references in his later slides, however I can't remember which equation he was referencing to for he gave several models during an earlier stage of the presentation.

We could use `hyperref` to get hyperlinks on the `\eqref`, but clicking it would go back to the original page where the equation was labeled, and somehow interrupt the presentation.

I have several workarounds in mind:
(1) exploit the `\pause` option as the overlay, once hitting space, the referenced equation would show. (2) use `tikz` to insert a `minipage` into the frame that contains the referenced equation.

However, both solutions require the referenced equation taking up spaces in the current slide the presenter is on, the best solution is still I said in the question title: mouse over the `\eqref` number, then a comment popping up showing the equation.

My google-fu leads me to a package called `comment`, however I didn't find any nice examples of how to use that package to produce beautiful slides.

Hence I wonder is it possible to produce some mouseover events like the title said, or any other workarounds are welcome too.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### The following is for people who have the **stable version of TeXLive** which ships out with `version 1.8` of `fancytooltips`.

**(For newer versions and other TeX distributions see below.)**

Here is a possibility using `fancytooltips` package by robert.marik.cz, who is also a regular in this site. See also related topic: [Showing the bibliographic entry in a popup when you hover over the citation key](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15356/showing-the-bibliographic-entry-in-a-popup-when-you-hover-over-the-citation-key) where robert demonstrated the package.

Here is the sample code. The text was taken from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle

### Code

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{EastLansing}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,graphicx,color}

\usepackage{tikz}
\PassOptionsToPackage{naturalnames}{hyperref}

\usepackage[inactive,blur=0.6, fixcolor]{fancytooltips}

\begin{document}

\FancyHook % Redefines \ref and \eqref commands to work with preview. See manual by running texdoc fancytooltips in your terminal


\title{A sample beamer presentation}
\author{Shuhao Cao}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{theorem}[Argument Principle]
If $f(z)$ is a meromorphic function inside and on some closed contour $C$, and $f$ has no zeros or poles on $C$, then
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1}
\oint \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} dz = 2\pi i(N-P)
\end{equation}
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
$N$ and $P$ of Equation \eqref{eq:1} denote respectively the number of zeros and poles of $f(z)$ inside the contour $C$, with each zero and pole counted as many times as its multiplicity, respectively order, indicates. 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Save this as file, say `myfile.tex`

Now, in your terminal, `cd` to your working directory. In order for the tool tips to work, you have to use the bundled script. You also have to download the [`Acrotex Education Bundle`](http://www.math.uakron.edu/~dpstory/webeq.html). For manual installing the needed package, you can download `eforms` and `insdljs` from the author's site: http://www.math.uakron.edu/~dpstory/webeq.html.

Now, in your terminal, run

`bash fancy-preview myfile`

Do not include the `.tex` file extension.

You can also use the option `mouseover` so that the equation will pop up by just hovering over the reference.

### Output

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

By the way, this only works with Adobe Reader.

### For version 1.12 dated 2012/06/12

MiKTeX users see additionally [Speravir's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83039).

The option `preview` for `fancytooltips` replaces the command `\FancyHook`. You can try the following code. The script `fancy-preview`is a Perl file, now. The AcroTeX packages are still needed (see above).

```
%For fancyequations version 1.12 
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{EastLansing}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,graphicx,color}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[inactive,mouseover,blur=0.6, fixcolor,preview]{fancytooltips}

\begin{document}

%\FancyHook % Redefines \ref and \eqref commands to work with preview. See manual by running texdoc fancytooltips in your terminal


\title{A sample beamer presentation}
\author{Shuhao Cao}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{theorem}[Argument Principle]
If $f(z)$ is a meromorphic function inside and on some closed contour $C$, and $f$ has no zeros or poles on $C$, then
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1}
\oint \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} dz = 2\pi i(N-P)
\end{equation}
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}
$N$ and $P$ of Equation \eqref{eq:1} denote respectively the number of zeros and poles of $f(z)$ inside the contour $C$, with each zero and pole counted as many times as its multiplicity, respectively order, indicates.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Compiling breaks in my machine with `bash fancy-preview myfile` but compiles fine with `perl fancy-preview myfile`.

Here is the screen shot with the latest version.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for putting these examples together! The latter example halfway through the compilation throws `LaTeX Warning: File 'myfile-a-crop.pdf' not found on input line 1.`, and as the result, the tooltip that I see is not the equation, but a bubble saying "myfile-a-crop.pdf". Do you have any ideas where I should start digging?

Answer (score 11):

This is thought as addition to [hpesoj626’s answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82352) for MiKTeX users:

- As already mentioned you need an installation of a Perl distribution, see in my answer to [MiKTeX and Perl scripts (and one Python script)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158796). Unfortunately you must additonally install the module `Config::IniFiles` by hand:
  In Strawberry Perl you go into the command line tool “CPAN Client” (can be reached over the start menu) and execute `upgrade Config::IniFiles` (the case of letters is relevant!). If ready press <kbd>q</kbd> for quitting the tool.
  In ActivePerl it is unluckily more complicated: Open the Perl Package Manager (found in the start menu), activate the view of all packages by clicking on the grey box in the toolbar or the according point in the menu “View” (or the right keyboard shortcut). Then search for `Config-IniFiles` (with `-` instead of the doubled colons) and mark this. After that press the <kbd>+</kbd> key or mark the box with this sign on it, and at last start the installation by clicking on the green arrow in the toolbar or with the keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Exit with the usual methods (keyboard shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>q</kbd>).
- The “AcroteX” bundle is only pre-installed in a *full* MiKTeX installation. If you opted for a basic installation, you need to manually install this bundle with the MiKTeX Package Manager.

For the next steps you need a local texmf tree, if you not yet have created one, see [Create a local texmf tree in MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69483/create-a-local-texmf-tree-in-miktex).

- The package `fancytooltips` requires the package `ocg`. It is part of `asymptote`, and this is neither part of basic MiKTeX nor can be installed with the Package Manager. The best would be to install the whole `asymptote` stuff, but if you are really sure, that you will only need `ocg`, I give you a solution here: Download http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/asymptote/doc/ocg.sty and put it in a recently created path `<localtexmf>\tex\latex\asymptote\`.

  *Update:* Since MiKTeX update from Dec 5 2012 you can *(and perhaps should)* use the new package `ocg-p`. A cite from documentation:

  > Important: If packages are used, which use the original `ocg` package then the `ocg-p` should be loaded after these packages. The `ocg` environment from the `ocg` package is replaced in this case.

  For a full Asymptote installation see [Using Asymptote with MiKTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83035/using-asymptote-with-miktex).
- The extensionless perl file `fancy-preview` must also be installed from other resources. You can download it from the website of the developer http://user.mendelu.cz/marik/fancy-preview/ (scroll to “Installation” at the very end). Put it in `<localtexmf>\scripts\fancytooltips\`.

  Now create an empty file in `<localtexmf>\bin\`. You can name it, as you want, as long the extension is `.bat` or `.cmd`, but the best is to give it the same name like the perl name, as I did here.

  Copy the following and paste it into `fancy-preview.bat`:

  ```
  @echo off
  SETLOCAL

  SET FPrevBAT=%~dp0
  SET FPrevPATH=%FPrevBAT:~0,-5%\scripts\fancytooltips

  perl %FPrevPATH%\fancy-preview %*
  ```

  Two remarks: First, when you save the file in Notepad or Wordpad, make sure, that there is no automatic appending of TXT extension – save the file name with double quotes: `"fancy-preview.bat"`. Second, this will only work with these paths as given by me.

After you‘ve refreshed the file name data base (FNDB) in MiKTeX, you can try the example shown in hpesoj626’s answer: In your workdir execute from the Windows Command Prompt `fancy-preview <example>`, note the execution *without any prepended `perl`*.

Comment: So, basically, you need to be a computer programmer.

Comment: @User17670 Why? I am not.

Comment: Well, as much as I'd like to have `fancy-preview` on my document (with 200+ equations), it just seems impenetrably difficult to set-up.

Comment: @User17670 I started reading with hope but when I reached this point, it just went out. Very difficult to me too. I hope there could be another way in the future.