# TeX Fancy-preview,fancytooltips, Perl library Config::IniFiles

Tags: fancytooltips

I was trying to get the LaTeX fancy preview running (http://user.mendelu.cz/marik/fancy-preview/#real) I think, I managed to get everything right but except for Config::IniFiles.
As pointed out at the end of the site one needs the Perl Config::IniFiles and i am totally unfamiliar to perl; so how do i  use Perl library Config::IniFiles to get the LaTeX fancytooltips output?

i am using windows7, 64Bit; MikTex

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm not sure this has anything to do with TeX and friends. What's the relationship?

Comment: According to the footnote on page 6 of the `fancytooltips` manual: either `cpan Config::IniFiles` or  `ppm install Config::Inifiles` will install the library. Run that in a command prompt I assume. Running just `ppm` will initialize a GUI, according to said footnote.

Comment: Just as reference: [“ … you need an installation of a Perl distribution … Unfortunately you must additonally install the module `Config::IniFiles` by hand: …”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83039/9237), and explanations for Strawberry Perl and AcitivePerl follow. One must know, that in the moment there is no module repository for ActivePerl 5.18.