# A problem with using fancytooltips package

Tags: math-mode, comments, pdfcomment, fancytooltips

I'm trying to use fancytooltips package to create comments/tips that include mathematical formulas (I use MikTeX 2.9). I acted according to the directions of this guide [Mouseover events in beamer: hovering on \eqref and a comment containing the original equation popping up](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82336/mouseover-events-in-beamer-hovering-on-eqref-and-a-comment-containing-the-orig). The next code has been taken from the link above with some changes.

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[russian]{article} 
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,graphicx,color}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[inactive,mouseover,preview]{fancytooltips}

\begin{document}

If $f(z)$ is a meromorphic function inside and on some closed contour $C$, and $f$ has no zeros or poles on $C$, then
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:1}
\oint \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} dz = 2\pi i(N-P)
\end{equation}

$N$ and $P$ of Equation \eqref{eq:1} denote respectively the number of zeros and poles of $f(z)$ inside the contour $C$, with each zero and pole counted as many times as its multiplicity, respectively order, indicates.


\end{document}
```

When I compile the file myfile.tex the error occurs:

`! Package pdftex.def Error: 'File myfile-a-crop.pdf' not found.`

As a result, instead of the required formula, this picture comes out:

[image]

I have not succeeded in fixing this error so far. This is an example of what I'm trying to get:

[image]

My final pdf file will contain many mathematical tasks with answers to them in the form of tooltips. Is there any simple way to achieve this?