# insert tooltips into PDF documents using LuaLaTeX – a popup window with equation appears if the mouse hovers on equation reference

Tags: luatex, pdfcomment, fancytooltips

I want to improve pdf readibility in following way. I know that [pdfcomments](https://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcomment) and [fancytooltips](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancytooltips/fancytooltips.pdf) packages are available, but I can't imagine whether it is possible following action. I wish to insert tooltips into PDF documents – a popup windows appears, if the mouse hovers on equation reference. The popup window should show to the reader the eqation written somewhere in the document.

Normally I use lualatex for pdf compilation, therefore it seems that I cannot use the solutions provided in [Mouseover events in beamer: hovering on \eqref and a comment containing the original equation popping up](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82336/mouseover-events-in-beamer-hovering-on-eqref-and-a-comment-containing-the-orig).

Comment: Is your question about (a) getting the data (the equation to display) or (b) using the tooltips? For the latter it is doable using OCG (eg https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155518/tooltip-that-works-with-all-pdf-readers ) and likely also using other packages. For (a) you will need to wrap something around the usual cross reference system.

Comment: On the other hand, if you want verbatim display, what you are describing is **already** built into a variety of PDF viewers. https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/52252/pdf-viewer-with-hyperlink-preview So maybe you should just suggest your reader to use one of those instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mouseover events in beamer: hovering on \eqref and a comment containing the original equation popping up](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82336/mouseover-events-in-beamer-hovering-on-eqref-and-a-comment-containing-the-orig) This shows that it is possible to set something up completely automatically to do the preview, but the automation is a bit complicated to set up.

Comment: But I am using lualatex. I can't to use pdflatex. And this is different story. I don't agree that the question has been already answered. Acrotex is bundled with pdflatex, if I am right. And many options of the fancytooltips package can be used only with pdflatex.