# Fancytooltips changes line spacing in beamer

Tags: beamer, fancytooltips

I try to show the *bibliographic entry in a popup* when the mouse pointer is over the citation key. To achieve this, I use the code from [Audrey's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15356/showing-the-bibliographic-entry-in-a-popup-when-you-hover-over-the-citation-key/48542#comment168533_48542). In the beamer class, this results in some line spacing issue: When supercite is used extra vertical space is added between the current and the upper line as the picture illustrates. In the first line of using just `\textsuperscript` everything works normal but in the second line when `\textsuperscript`and `\tooltip` is used in combination the line spacing changes.

[image]

So, I reduced the problem down to this MWE, but don't know what to do now.

```
% --- tooltip document
\begin{filecontents*}{fancytipmark.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[createtips]{fancytooltips}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{noheadfoot,nomarginpar,margin=0in,paperwidth=4in,paperheight=1in}
\pagestyle{empty}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
\keytip{citekey} abc
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

% --- presentation document
\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[filename=fancytipmark, mouseover, movetips]{fancytooltips}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.\textsuperscript{1}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.\textsuperscript{\tooltip{1}{citekey}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\smash`:

```
% --- tooltip document
\begin{filecontents*}{fancytipmark.tex}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[createtips]{fancytooltips}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{noheadfoot,nomarginpar,margin=0in,paperwidth=4in,paperheight=1in}
\pagestyle{empty}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
\keytip{citekey} abc
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

% --- presentation document
\documentclass[8pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[filename=fancytipmark, mouseover, movetips]{fancytooltips}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.\textsuperscript{1}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.\textsuperscript{\smash{\tooltip{1}{citekey}}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]