# File biblatex.sty and eforms.sty not found

Tags: packages, fancytooltips

I tried compiling a file that uses the `fancytooltips` package, according to Gonzalo Medina's answer at [Showing the bibliographic entry in a popup when you hover over the citation key](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15356/showing-the-bibliographic-entry-in-a-popup-when-you-hover-over-the-citation-key). And it cannot find some .sty files. How can I fix it? I'm on Ubuntu and compiling on command line using `pdflatex`.

```
! LaTeX Error: File `biblatex.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/fancytooltips/fancytooltips.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/ms/everyshi.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/etc/texmf/tex/latex/config/graphics.cfg)))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/eso-pic/eso-pic.sty)

Package fancytooltips Warning: ** The filename with tooltips is not given. ** o
n input line 52.


! LaTeX Error: File `eforms.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:
```

Comment: have you seen [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437) and [How to install "vanilla" TeXLive on Debian or Ubuntu?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1092)

Comment: @cmhughes Ah thanks, I'm installing TexLive right now.

Comment: What does `kpsewhich biblatex.sty` return?

Comment: @jon Ah, looks like it's able to find `biblatex.sty` now. `kpsewhich biblatex.sty` `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty`

Comment: OK, so it is 'findable'.  Can you post a minimal example file that fails with the error you describe.  Something like `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{biblatex}\begin{document}test\end{document}` should do the trick....