# No \citation, \bibdata, \bibstyle commands

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I tried compiling a file that uses the `fancytooltips` package, according to Gonzalo Medina's answer at [Showing the bibliographic entry in a popup when you hover over the citation key](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15356/showing-the-bibliographic-entry-in-a-popup-when-you-hover-over-the-citation-key). I was able to do `pdflatex bibtips.tex`. It produces the `.aux` file:

```
\relax 
\abx@aux@sortscheme{nty}
\abx@aux@cite{goossens93}
\@writefile{toc}{\boolfalse {citerequest}\boolfalse {citetracker}\boolfalse {pagetracker}\boolfalse {backtracker}\relax }
\@writefile{lof}{\boolfalse {citerequest}\boolfalse {citetracker}\boolfalse {pagetracker}\boolfalse {backtracker}\relax }
\@writefile{lot}{\boolfalse {citerequest}\boolfalse {citetracker}\boolfalse {pagetracker}\boolfalse {backtracker}\relax }
\abx@aux@cite{knuth79}
```

But when I tried doing `bibtex bibtips.aux`, the result is

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2012)
The top-level auxiliary file: bibtips.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file bibtips.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file bibtips.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file bibtips.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you load `biblatex` with the `backend=bibtex` option?  (Also you can't do `biblatex bibtex.tex`; that should produce an error in your terminal.)

Comment: Sorry, I meant `pdflatex` -- just edited. And no, I didn't do any `backend=bibtex`. I simply copied over the first two files from Gonzalo Medina's post in that link.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina If I run `bibtex bibtips`, it produces the same result as in my original post. And I'm not sure what you mean by `biber`. Is that a command?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Running `bibtex bibtips.tex` gives `I couldn't open file name 'bibtips.tex.aux'`.

Comment: This is the sequence: `pdflatex file.tex`, `bibtex file.aux`, `pdflatex file.tex`, `pdflatex file.tex`.  And you should tell `biblatex` that you want to use `bibtex` by doing something like `\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}`

Comment: @jon Ok, I got Gonzalo's second file working. Now on to the third file... I added `\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}` and compiled it again `pdflatex real.tex`... and it stops at `LaTeX Error: File 'eforms.sty' not found.`. Doing `kpsewhich eforms.sty` returns nothing. Why might that be?

Comment: That is not a package that ships with TeX Live.  (I don't have it either.)  You need to download the [acrotex bundle](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/acrotex) and install it manually.