LaTeX Workshop (VS Code) finds biber.exe succesfully but logs and outputs error
OS: Windows 10
Installed Tex Live
Installed LaTeX Workshop extension on VS code
Changed settings.json to support biber as described here
Now after I run latexmk -> biber -> latexmk*2 recipe, my pdf compiles fully succesfully, including bibliography, but I receive the following error in the log:
[16:55:48.928][Build] Recipe step 2 The command is biber:["QUATORZE14BIS"].
[16:55:48.929][Build] env: undefined
[16:55:48.929][Build] root: %WS1%\QUATORZE14BIS.tex
[16:55:48.930][Build] cwd: %WS1%
[16:55:48.993][Build] LaTeX build process spawned with PID 3880.
[16:55:50.068][Event] AUTO_CLEANED
[16:55:52.562][Parser][BiberLog] Logged 0 messages.
[16:55:52.562][Build] Recipe returns with error code 2/null on PID 3880.
[16:55:52.562][Build] Does the executable exist? $PATH: undefined, ... SOME OTHER WINDOWS PATH OPTIONS ... D:\Jonas\PROGRAMS\texlive\2024\bin\windows, $SHELL: undefined
[16:55:52.563][Build] 

"D:\Jonas\PROGRAMS\texlive\2024\bin\windows" does indeed contain a biber.exe. And it seems like it actually does find this biber.exe, because my bibliography is generated succesfully.
The bibliography is created as follows:
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{abbrev3,crypto,biblio, Quatorze14bis}

A .blg file is created which contains the following:
[0] Config.pm:308> INFO - This is Biber 2.20
[0] Config.pm:311> INFO - Logfile is 'QUATORZE14BIS.blg'
[179] biber-MSWIN64:340> INFO - === 
[906] Utils.pm:410> ERROR - Cannot find 'QUATORZE14BIS.bcf'!
[906] Biber.pm:136> INFO - ERRORS: 1

How do I find further information on how what is causing this error? Because evidently it is finding biber.exe: the .blg file would otherwise not be created.

Biber only works with biblatex, not the 'classical' \bibliographystyle approach

latexmk will automatically run the latex multiple times and the appropriate bibliography tools. No need to do latexmk -> biber -> latexmk*2  even if you were to use biblatex. Run latexmk once.

Ok, the reason I go through this whole misery is because previously I received the No \citation, \bibdata or \bibstyle command error

...and now it seems to have magically gone, and I don't get the error anymore when I just call \latexmk. So now I'm even more confused. Because https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/406205/no-citation-bibdata-or-bibstyle-command told me to use Biber

When you use biblatex you should use biber. But in the example above, you don't use biblatex but classic \bibliographystyle and \bibliography commands. So you need to use BibTeX. I would suggest to read a (not too short) LaTeX introduction and also at least the basic information in the manuals of the used packages …

ok, I get that using biber is a mistake. I'm now trying to get the original "No \citation, \bibdata or \bibstyle command" error back because I want to know why that didn't work like it does now!

Just remove the \bibliographystyle and the \bibliography command. Do a new LaTeX run and then run BibTeX and you will get the error back. And then compare the aux file of a LaTeX run with and without these commands … And because biblatex does not use these commands (unless you configure it to use backend bibtex), you get the error message from bibtex also, if you'd use biblatex for your bibliography and do a bibtex run instead of a biber run.

See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-or-bold-citation-key-instead-of-citation-number and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/703371/277964

Thanks for letting me know. I understand now that I was using the wrong program (Biber or biblatex) with the wrong commands (\bibiliographystyle and \bibiliography instead of \usepackage{biblatex})

What I don't understand is how I got the
"I found no \citation commands BibTeX
I found no \bibdata command BibTeX
I found no \bibstyle command BibTeX"
errors in the first place.
I've never had \usepackage{biblatex} anywhere in my texfiles!

either your document didn't include e.g. \bibliographystyle or you had other errors which prevented the information being written correctly to the .aux. bibtex doesn't examine your .tex file. it reads the .aux generated from a previous compilation.

@cfr That is indeed the case. I had an error previously which caused the aux to abort (cls package had trouble with some hyper link package needing to be loaded in another order, fixed by updating cls)
This now explains everything. Thanks everyone!

It's always the same: Don't ignore errors while LaTeX runs. It does not make sense to run bibtex, if there are errors in your document preamble. Running bibtex after errors reported by LaTeX makes only sense, if the errors are in the bib-file and you have corrected the bib-file. Otherwise you first should have an error-free LaTeX run.

@cabohah Yes. Definitely not a mistake I will make again!
The problem was that this is the first day I'm using Latex Workshop from moving from overleaf, and when clicking the "notification" from latex, it points to the bibtex error rather than the latex error. Hence why I started (mistakenly) checking that first.

As @Joseph_Wright and @Cabolah point out, the situation in my code was the following:
I was calling commands meant for BibTeX:
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{abbrev3,crypto,biblio, Quatorze14bis}

while attempting to use biber, which as the Not Too Short introduction states (page 127) are not the right commands.
The reason I was doing this is that BibTeX was outputting errors that I mistakenly thought were due to Biber being needed rather than BibTex. It turns out that the error "no citation, bibdata, or bibstyle found in .aux file" will trigger as soon as there is some error in your Tex file, and this error message is forwarded to Latex Workshop. This makes it seems that the "no citation, bibdata, or bibstyle found in .aux file" is the primary error in your file, while in reality it is simply the result of errors in the tex file.
