# Move-around box in PDF display

Tags: pdf, javascript, fancytooltips

I tried using the [`fancytooltips`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancytooltips) package and like it a lot. One thing that I could imagine would be nice is to have the entry showing up as a movable box instead of just a tooltip. (Sometimes the tooltip obscures other text.) Is this possible at all to implement? I mean it could take a lot of work, but if it's possible at all I'd like to look into it.

The examples and screenshots of `fancytooltips` can be found in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/54831/22886). To quote from that post:

---

Both Gonzalo Medina and Audrey posted an excellent solution. But the things are simpler now. See the [`fancy-preview`](http://user.mendelu.cz/marik/fancy-preview/) webpage - based on the new version of `fancytooltips` (May 2012), `preview.sty` and some bash scripts you get tooltips for bibliographic entries, theorems, definitions, displayed equations etc. automatically.

Small example and screenshots are attached.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\usepackage{hyperref} % Important!
\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}[Lemma from \cite{M}]\label{lemma}
  If $k<0$, then
  \begin{equation}
    \label{eq:1}
    x^2+k<x^2
  \end{equation}
  for every real number $x$.
\end{lemma}

Inequality \eqref{eq:1} in Lema \ref{lemma} can be proved easily. Is
more general than \cite[Theorem 3.4]{K}.

\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem[M]{M} Me: My book related to the problem (2006), 145 p.
  % The new line is important!

\bibitem{K} Karl: Karl's paper published in some minor proceedings, 
    a local conferrence organized by his university (2005), 23--25.
  % The new line is important!


\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

**The file in Adobe Reader**

[image]

**Ref M**

[image]

**Ref 1**

[image]

**Equation (1)**

[image]

**Lemma 1.**

[image]

Comment: Just because many users (like me) might not be familiar with `fancytooltips`, could you add a MWE, perhaps even demonstrating the problematic overlap, and a picture of the output?

Comment: @doncherry Good point, I've just edited to add that!

Comment: Thanks! Perhaps you could even include (reproduce) it in this question? We kind of like to have everything in one place.

Comment: @doncherry Done!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This would require hacking the `fancytooltips` package.

Since `fancytooltips` depends on packages which are not in TeXLive, I tried something on my own.

The tool-tip command defined below supports all common output drivers (LaTeX workflows):

- `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf` (`dvips` must not be called with option `-Ppdf`!)
- `latex`->`dvipdfmx`
- `xelatex`, `lualatex`, `pdflatex`

---

The command

```
\tooltip[<link text colour>]{<link text>}[<tip box colour>]{<tip text>}
```

creates a tooltip that can be dragged around.

The colour arguments are optional and default to `blue` and `yellow!20`. Predefined colour names and colour expressions according to the colour-model  of the `xcolor` package can be used. If`hyperref` is loaded, its colour setting for internal links (option `linkcolor`) is used as `<link text colour>`.

`<link text>` is breakable across line endings, except for the `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf` workflow.

Multi-line `<tip text>` should be put into a `\parbox` or `minipage`.

```
\documentclass[a6paper,12pt]{scrbook}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% tooltips with LaTeX v. 2017/11/28
%
% \tooltip[*[*[*[*]]]][<link colour>]{<link text>}[<tip box colour>]{<tip text>}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%   \tooltip     --> draggable tip, visible on mouse-over, hidden on mouse-out
%               
%   \tooltip*    --> draggable tip, toggle visiblity on mouse-over
%               
%   \tooltip**   --> NON-draggable tip, visible on mouse-over, hidden on mouse-out
%              
%   \tooltip***  --> NON-draggable tip, toggle visiblity on mouse-over
%               
%   \tooltip**** --> NON-draggable tip, toggle visiblity on mouse-click (Evince!)
%
% Default link colour can be set with
%
%   \usepackage[linkcolor=<colour>]{hyperref}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{pdfbase}[2017/03/16]
\usepackage{xparse,ocgbase}
\usepackage{xcolor,calc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\tpPdfLink\pbs_pdflink:nn
\let\tpPdfAnnot\pbs_pdfannot:nnnn\let\tpPdfLastAnn\pbs_pdflastann:
\let\tpAppendToFields\pbs_appendtofields:n
\def\tpPdfXform{\pbs_pdfxform:nnnnn{1}{1}{}{}}
\let\tpPdfLastXform\pbs_pdflastxform:
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\tooltip}{%
  ssssO{\ifdefined\@linkcolor\@linkcolor\else blue\fi}mO{yellow!20}m%
}{{%
  \leavevmode%
  \IfBooleanT{#2}{%
    %for variants with two and more stars, put tip box on a PDF Layer (OCG)
    \ocgbase@new@ocg{tipOCG.\thetcnt}{%
      /Print<</PrintState/OFF>>/Export<</ExportState/OFF>>%
    }{false}%
    \xdef\tpTipOcg{\ocgbase@last@ocg}%
    %prevent simultaneous visibility of multiple non-draggable tooltips
    \ocgbase@add@ocg@to@radiobtn@grp{tool@tips}{\ocgbase@last@ocg}%
  }%
  \tpPdfLink{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#4}{%
      /Subtype/Link/Border[0 0 0]/A <</S/SetOCGState/State [/Toggle \tpTipOcg]>>
    }{%
      /Subtype/Screen%
      /AA<<%
        \IfBooleanTF{#3}{%
          /E<</S/SetOCGState/State [/Toggle \tpTipOcg]>>%
        }{%  
          \IfBooleanTF{#2}{%
            /E<</S/SetOCGState/State [/ON \tpTipOcg]>>%
            /X<</S/SetOCGState/State [/OFF \tpTipOcg]>>%
          }{
            \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
              /E<</S/JavaScript/JS(%
                var fd=this.getField('tip.\thetcnt');%
                if(typeof(click\thetcnt)=='undefined'){%
                  var click\thetcnt=false;%
                  var fdor\thetcnt=fd.rect;var dragging\thetcnt=false;%
                }%
                if(fd.display==display.hidden){%
                  fd.delay=true;fd.display=display.visible;fd.delay=false;%
                }else{%
                  if(!click\thetcnt&&!dragging\thetcnt){fd.display=display.hidden;}%
                  if(!dragging\thetcnt){click\thetcnt=false;}%
                }%
                this.dirty=false;%
              )>>%
            }{%
              /E<</S/JavaScript/JS(%
                var fd=this.getField('tip.\thetcnt');%
                if(typeof(click\thetcnt)=='undefined'){%
                  var click\thetcnt=false;%
                  var fdor\thetcnt=fd.rect;var dragging\thetcnt=false;%
                }%
                if(fd.display==display.hidden){%
                  fd.delay=true;fd.display=display.visible;fd.delay=false;%
                }%
               this.dirty=false;%
              )>>%
              /X<</S/JavaScript/JS(%
                if(!click\thetcnt&&!dragging\thetcnt){fd.display=display.hidden;}%
                if(!dragging\thetcnt){click\thetcnt=false;}%
                this.dirty=false;%
              )>>%
            }%  
            /U<</S/JavaScript/JS(click\thetcnt=true;this.dirty=false;)>>%
            /PC<</S/JavaScript/JS (%
              var fd=this.getField('tip.\thetcnt');%
              try{fd.rect=fdor\thetcnt;}catch(e){}%
              fd.display=display.hidden;this.dirty=false;%
            )>>%
            /PO<</S/JavaScript/JS(this.dirty=false;)>>%
          }%
        }%
      >>%
    }%
  }{{\color{#5}#6}}%
  \sbox\tiptext{%
    \IfBooleanT{#2}{%
      \ocgbase@oc@bdc{\tpTipOcg}\ocgbase@open@stack@push{\tpTipOcg}}%
    \fcolorbox{black}{#7}{#8}%
    \IfBooleanT{#2}{\ocgbase@oc@emc\ocgbase@open@stack@pop\tpNull}%
  }%
  \edef\twd{\the\wd\tiptext}%
  \edef\tht{\the\ht\tiptext}%
  \edef\tdp{\the\dp\tiptext}%
  \measureremainder{\whatsleft}\tipshift=0pt%
  \ifdim\whatsleft<\twd\setlength\tipshift{\whatsleft-\twd}\fi%
  \IfBooleanF{#2}{\tpPdfXform{\tiptext}}%
  \raisebox{\heightof{#6}+\tdp}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{\tipshift}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#2}{\usebox{\tiptext}}{%
      \tpPdfAnnot{\twd}{\tht}{\tdp}{%
        /Subtype/Widget/FT/Btn/T (tip.\thetcnt)%
        /AP<</N \tpPdfLastXform>>%
        /MK<</TP 1/I \tpPdfLastXform/IF<</S/A/FB true/A [0.0 0.0]>>>>%
        /Ff 65536/F 3%
        /AA <<%
          /U <<%
            /S/JavaScript/JS(%
              var fd=event.target;%
              var mX=this.mouseX;var mY=this.mouseY;%
              var drag=function(){%
                var nX=this.mouseX;var nY=this.mouseY;%
                var dX=nX-mX;var dY=nY-mY;%
                var fdr=fd.rect;%
                fdr[0]+=dX;fdr[1]+=dY;fdr[2]+=dX;fdr[3]+=dY;%
                fd.rect=fdr;mX=nX;mY=nY;%
              };%
              if(!dragging\thetcnt){%
                dragging\thetcnt=true;Int=app.setInterval("drag()",1);%
              }%
              else{app.clearInterval(Int);dragging\thetcnt=false;}%
              this.dirty=false;%
            )%
          >>%
        >>%
      }%
      \tpAppendToFields{\tpPdfLastAnn}%
    }%
  }}%
  \stepcounter{tcnt}%
}}
\makeatother
\newsavebox\tiptext\newcounter{tcnt}
\newlength{\whatsleft}\newlength{\tipshift}
\newcommand{\measureremainder}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \path let \p0 = (0,0), \p1 = (current page.east) in
      [/utils/exec={\pgfmathsetlength#1{\x1-\x0}\global#1=#1}];
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}\Huge
Einstein's \tooltip{formula}{$E=m c^2$} is well known.
  Another famous formula is due to \tooltip{Pythagoras}{$a^2+b^2=c^2$}.
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

How it works:

Two PDF-Annotations (mouse-sensitive regions) are created: (1) A link around the blue link text, which is breakable across line endings. (2) An interactive (`/Ff 65536`) button (`/FT/Btn`) widget (`/Subtype/Widget`) for the tip text.

Visibility of the tip box is controlled via a JavaScript action that is bound to the mouse-enter event of the link. In order to show/hide the tip it is sufficient to repeatedly hover the mouse pointer over the link text.

The tip text may *not* be directly embedded into the page content; it couldn't be moved around otherwise. Rather, it is typeset into a box (`\sbox`) and subsequently distilled into a so-called Form-XObject, which is a self-contained PDF entity with graphical and/or textual content. This Form-XObject is bound to the button widget appearance via the `/MK` entry.

The dragging is implemented as a JavaScript action, which is triggered by the mouse-up event of the tip-text button. The mouse movement is tracked by the function `drag()` which is repeatedly executed using a JavaScript timer (`app.setInterval`). The deltas of the mouse position thus determined are continuously added to the coordinates (`rect` property) of the JavaScript `Field` object that represents the tip-text button.

Comment: That looks great, AlexG! Could you please add some comment on what each part of your code is doing, so that I (and others) can understand it more easily? Thanks!

Comment: Currently I am a bit short of time. Will do that later.

Comment: @MikaH: ...Done. Plus some code fixes.

Comment: @AlexG Mother of God! img.mu.cdn.li/Ao/xqefEH.jpg Excellent work! Questions: Could it be made so that (in your MWE) "formula" could be replaced by `\eqref{}`, if you know what I mean? Also, does the end-user require anything other than a PDF viewer?

Comment: @User17670: First, we would need to redefine the `equation` environment such that it puts the equation in an `\sbox` in addition to typesetting it onto the page. Then, `\eqref` cannot be used as it only inserts the equation number (we do not really want to change this!). Instead, we need a new macro, say, `\eqrepeat{...}`, to be used as `<tip text>`, which inserts the previously typeset equation using `\usebox`. As for requirements, `pdflatex` is used for typesetting; the end-user only needs AdobeReader. I could extend this code to different drivers (dvips->ps2pdf, XeLaTeX, ...), if needed.

Comment: @AlexG To clarify: The command `\tooltip{formula}` produces the word "formula" in the PDF, in red, and as a clickable object. But, say I'm referring to an equation that was introduced 3 section ago, whose `\label` is `"GoodEq"` and whose number in the PDF is "(3.12)"  I'd like to write, `"using \eqref{GoodEq} we see that..."`  to give a PDF output of  "using (3.12) we see that...", where the "(3.12)" part is clickable. This would be very useful and very cool.

Comment: @User17670: `\eqref{GoodEq}` would have to go as the first arg of the tooltip macro, and `\eqrepeat{GoodEq}` as its second arg to be shown as draggable tip text: "`using \tooltip{\eqref{GoodEq}}{\eqrepeat{GoodEq}} we see that ...`". The macro `\eqrepeat` would need to be implemented as outlined in my previous comment.

Comment: I can post this as a question, but when I copy/paste/compile the above code, I get an error message for each use of `\tooltip`. The message reads: `! Undefined control sequence.
\tooltip code ...@pdfborder {0 0 0}\fi \tpPdfLink 
                                                  {/Subtype/Screen/AA<</E<</...
l.70 Einstein's \tooltip{formula}{$E=m c^2$}` It seems to choke on the \tpPdfLink command. I am using TeXLive 2012, pdflatex. Can anyone help?

Comment: @GregH: I am using TeXLive-2012 too. Try a package update (`tlmgr update --self --all`), maybe `media9` in your TeX installation is outdated. (It is required here.)

Comment: For ***further updates*** of the `\tooltip` command, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/111932