# How can I use fancytooltips in Windows OS?

Tags: pdf, windows, fancytooltips

In many earlier posts I read about fancytooltip. However, I installed this package in Windows 32bit OS from [ctan website](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancytooltips). In some examples of this website such as [tex.stackexchange.com post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/108998/108724) used  pdfbase and ocgbase packages that i installed  before but my TexLive don't find them and I get the error

"*! LaTeX Error: File `ocgbase.sty' not found."*.

I have same problem with Web.sty package. How can I use fancytooltips in Windows OS? If this packages are not for Windows OS, why is this package placed on the website?

Thanks.

Comment: You should use TeX Live Package Manager instead of installing by hand.

Comment: Which LaTeX distribution do you use? Why install it from CTAN, isn't it available via TeX Live?

Comment: @Bernard, The texlive package manager can't find this packages.

Comment: @ilFuria, My Latex distribution is TeX Live 2015.

Comment: @C.F.G uhm, I don't know if the TeX Live package manager works with older distributions. Are there any good reasons not to upgrade to 2016?

Comment: @ilfuria, If I upgrade my Tex Live, my problem will be solved?

Comment: @C.F.G I actually cannot tell, both because I don't use that package and I don't have a windows machine. Regardless, I think it's best just to use the latest TeX Live, since it has many perks (e.g. package updates). It's also more likely to have relevant answers here, if you refer to the latest release. So my strategy is that, if you don't have a valid reason to upgrade (e.g. you use packages that no longer exist and do not have time to search for their replacements), it's always the best to upgrade. But I can't guarantee that this will solve your problem

Comment: `fancytooltips` is on TL 2015 and I remember back in TL 2013, it was there too!

Comment: @ilfuria Ok. I want to upgrade my Tex Live to 2016.

Comment: @ilfuria Thanks. this problem is solved in TexLive 2016.

Comment: @C.F.G no problem, pal!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because solved by update