# Can't embed hyperlink references in a tooltip

Tags: hyperref, scripts, tooltips, hypertarget

I'm having troubles trying to embed text references in a tooltip.
I'm using the tooltip script which can be found here: [Tooltip that works with all pdf readers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155518/tooltip-that-works-with-all-pdf-readers#answer-164186).
I'm also using the `hyperref` package.
Unfortunately, I can't insert references in a tooltip.
*Code*:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}

% Insert the tooltip script here

\begin{document}

\hypertarget{test}{foo}
\newpage
This is a \href{test}{reference}
This is a \tooltip{tooltip with reference}{Reference \href{test}{here}}

\end{document}
```

*Error*: **link annotations cannot be inside an XForm.**

If I comment the line with the tooltip, building the pdf doesn't produce any error. References doesn't seems to be compatible with tooltips as it's use XForm. Would it be possible to combine both commands though? Maybe by editing the script?

Comment: Originally, the `\tooltip` macro was implemented to satisfy a request for a [↗Move-around box in PDF display](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/107247). This involves putting the box content into a PDF Form XObject first, which is then used as the appearance of a PDF Widget Annotation (whose `Rect` coordinates can be changed by JavaScript to allow for moving it around). Links cannot be embedded into a Form XObject, as you have already noticed. I need some time to think about your request.

Comment: Done, see below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the new version 2017/10/25 of the [`↗\tooltip`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/164186) macro it should be possible to also place internal links and URLs into the tip box.

We must, however, patch `hyperref` a little bit in order to also have the interactive link rectangle disappear when the tip is hidden.

Here, we use the triply-starred `\tooltip***` variant which *toggles* the tip box visibility on mouse-over. It allows us to move the mouse pointer onto the link inside the tip box. A second wipe hides the tip box.

---

**Complete example:**

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{hyperref}
%patch hyperref to make PDF Annotations PDF-Layer-(OCG)-aware
\makeatletter
  \let\Hy@setpdfborderOrig\Hy@setpdfborder
  \def\Hy@setpdfborder{\ocgbase@insert@oc\Hy@setpdfborderOrig}%
\makeatother

%\usepackage[ocgcolorlinks]{ocgx2}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% tooltips with LaTeX v. 2017/11/28
%
% \tooltip[*[*[*[*]]]][<link colour>]{<link text>}[<tip box colour>]{<tip text>}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%   \tooltip     --> draggable tip, visible on mouse-over, hidden on mouse-out
%               
%   \tooltip*    --> draggable tip, toggle visiblity on mouse-over
%               
%   \tooltip**   --> NON-draggable tip, visible on mouse-over, hidden on mouse-out
%              
%   \tooltip***  --> NON-draggable tip, toggle visiblity on mouse-over
%               
%   \tooltip**** --> NON-draggable tip, toggle visiblity on mouse-click (Evince!)
%
% Default link colour can be set with
%
%   \usepackage[linkcolor=<colour>]{hyperref}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{pdfbase}[2017/03/16]
\usepackage{xparse,ocgbase}
\usepackage{xcolor,calc}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\tpPdfLink\pbs_pdflink:nn
\let\tpPdfAnnot\pbs_pdfannot:nnnn\let\tpPdfLastAnn\pbs_pdflastann:
\let\tpAppendToFields\pbs_appendtofields:n
\def\tpPdfXform{\pbs_pdfxform:nnnnn{1}{1}{}{}}
\let\tpPdfLastXform\pbs_pdflastxform:
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\tooltip}{%
  ssssO{\ifdefined\@linkcolor\@linkcolor\else blue\fi}mO{yellow!20}m%
}{{%
  \leavevmode%
  \IfBooleanT{#2}{%
    %for variants with two and more stars, put tip box on a PDF Layer (OCG)
    \ocgbase@new@ocg{tipOCG.\thetcnt}{%
      /Print<</PrintState/OFF>>/Export<</ExportState/OFF>>%
    }{false}%
    \xdef\tpTipOcg{\ocgbase@last@ocg}%
    %prevent simultaneous visibility of multiple non-draggable tooltips
    \ocgbase@add@ocg@to@radiobtn@grp{tool@tips}{\ocgbase@last@ocg}%
  }%
  \tpPdfLink{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#4}{%
      /Subtype/Link/Border[0 0 0]/A <</S/SetOCGState/State [/Toggle \tpTipOcg]>>
    }{%
      /Subtype/Screen%
      /AA<<%
        \IfBooleanTF{#3}{%
          /E<</S/SetOCGState/State [/Toggle \tpTipOcg]>>%
        }{%  
          \IfBooleanTF{#2}{%
            /E<</S/SetOCGState/State [/ON \tpTipOcg]>>%
            /X<</S/SetOCGState/State [/OFF \tpTipOcg]>>%
          }{
            \IfBooleanTF{#1}{%
              /E<</S/JavaScript/JS(%
                var fd=this.getField('tip.\thetcnt');%
                if(typeof(click\thetcnt)=='undefined'){%
                  var click\thetcnt=false;%
                  var fdor\thetcnt=fd.rect;var dragging\thetcnt=false;%
                }%
                if(fd.display==display.hidden){%
                  fd.delay=true;fd.display=display.visible;fd.delay=false;%
                }else{%
                  if(!click\thetcnt&&!dragging\thetcnt){fd.display=display.hidden;}%
                  if(!dragging\thetcnt){click\thetcnt=false;}%
                }%
                this.dirty=false;%
              )>>%
            }{%
              /E<</S/JavaScript/JS(%
                var fd=this.getField('tip.\thetcnt');%
                if(typeof(click\thetcnt)=='undefined'){%
                  var click\thetcnt=false;%
                  var fdor\thetcnt=fd.rect;var dragging\thetcnt=false;%
                }%
                if(fd.display==display.hidden){%
                  fd.delay=true;fd.display=display.visible;fd.delay=false;%
                }%
               this.dirty=false;%
              )>>%
              /X<</S/JavaScript/JS(%
                if(!click\thetcnt&&!dragging\thetcnt){fd.display=display.hidden;}%
                if(!dragging\thetcnt){click\thetcnt=false;}%
                this.dirty=false;%
              )>>%
            }%  
            /U<</S/JavaScript/JS(click\thetcnt=true;this.dirty=false;)>>%
            /PC<</S/JavaScript/JS (%
              var fd=this.getField('tip.\thetcnt');%
              try{fd.rect=fdor\thetcnt;}catch(e){}%
              fd.display=display.hidden;this.dirty=false;%
            )>>%
            /PO<</S/JavaScript/JS(this.dirty=false;)>>%
          }%
        }%
      >>%
    }%
  }{{\color{#5}#6}}%
  \sbox\tiptext{%
    \IfBooleanT{#2}{%
      \ocgbase@oc@bdc{\tpTipOcg}\ocgbase@open@stack@push{\tpTipOcg}}%
    \fcolorbox{black}{#7}{#8}%
    \IfBooleanT{#2}{\ocgbase@oc@emc\ocgbase@open@stack@pop\tpNull}%
  }%
  \edef\twd{\the\wd\tiptext}%
  \edef\tht{\the\ht\tiptext}%
  \edef\tdp{\the\dp\tiptext}%
  \measureremainder{\whatsleft}\tipshift=0pt%
  \ifdim\whatsleft<\twd\setlength\tipshift{\whatsleft-\twd}\fi%
  \IfBooleanF{#2}{\tpPdfXform{\tiptext}}%
  \raisebox{\heightof{#6}+\tdp}[0pt][0pt]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\hspace{\tipshift}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#2}{\usebox{\tiptext}}{%
      \tpPdfAnnot{\twd}{\tht}{\tdp}{%
        /Subtype/Widget/FT/Btn/T (tip.\thetcnt)%
        /AP<</N \tpPdfLastXform>>%
        /MK<</TP 1/I \tpPdfLastXform/IF<</S/A/FB true/A [0.0 0.0]>>>>%
        /Ff 65536/F 3%
        /AA <<%
          /U <<%
            /S/JavaScript/JS(%
              var fd=event.target;%
              var mX=this.mouseX;var mY=this.mouseY;%
              var drag=function(){%
                var nX=this.mouseX;var nY=this.mouseY;%
                var dX=nX-mX;var dY=nY-mY;%
                var fdr=fd.rect;%
                fdr[0]+=dX;fdr[1]+=dY;fdr[2]+=dX;fdr[3]+=dY;%
                fd.rect=fdr;mX=nX;mY=nY;%
              };%
              if(!dragging\thetcnt){%
                dragging\thetcnt=true;Int=app.setInterval("drag()",1);%
              }%
              else{app.clearInterval(Int);dragging\thetcnt=false;}%
              this.dirty=false;%
            )%
          >>%
        >>%
      }%
      \tpAppendToFields{\tpPdfLastAnn}%
    }%
  }}%
  \stepcounter{tcnt}%
}}
\makeatother
\newsavebox\tiptext\newcounter{tcnt}
\newlength{\whatsleft}\newlength{\tipshift}
\newcommand{\measureremainder}[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
    \path let \p0 = (0,0), \p1 = (current page.east) in
      [/utils/exec={\pgfmathsetlength#1{\x1-\x0}\global#1=#1}];
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
  This is a \tooltip***{tooltip with reference}{Go to \hyperlink{test}{foo}.}

  This is a less useful \tooltip**{tooltip with reference}{Go to \hyperlink{test}{foo}.} because it does not allow you to reach the embedded link.

\newpage  

  \hypertarget{test}{foo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks you a lot Alex! Even if references cannot completely be embedded in a _mouse-over_ tooltip, your solution suits to me and only requires a few small changes in the code.

Comment: We could add a 3rd star to create `\tooltip***` which *toggles* tip visibility on mouse-over. This would allow us to reach an embedded link.

Comment: This would definitively be awesome! Do you have any idea how could we implement it?

Comment: Ok, updated the code.