# Tooltips compatible with Mac OS X preview.app

Tags: bibtex, pdftex, pdf, mac

I would like to achieve hover-over tooltips for bibtex entires as mentioned in [this previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15356/showing-the-bibliographic-entry-in-a-popup-when-you-hover-over-the-citation-key), but all solutions (e.g. involving cooltooltips, fancytooltips) do not seem to be compatible with my pdf viewer: Mac OS X Preview.app version 5.5.3.

Is there a solution out there for Preview?

It seems feasible given that the examples listed on [a stackoverflow response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14200958/148668) seem to work correctly (for general PDFs, not necessarily created via latex):

http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part2/chapter07/movie_posters_2.pdf
http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part2/chapter07/timetable_help.pdf

Comment: Hi, your examples are simply PDF annotations which can be included by cooltooltips or pdfcomment packages. For fancytooltips you need Adobe Reader.