# Preview of "hyperlinks" in PDF

Tags: hyperref, pdf

Let's say I am using the `hyperref` package, which automatically hyperlinks `eqref`, `cite`, etc.

I know its a stretch, but has anyone ever encountered a PDF viewer (I'm very happy with Sumatra) that can show a small balloon when I hover over such a link, that shows the linked equation or bibliography item? Instead of having to click on it and jump to the correct page.

Comment: Take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15356/showing-the-bibliographic-entry-in-a-popup-when-you-hover-over-the-citation-key/54831#54831

Comment: Whatever you want, it will not work with SumatraPDF: It does not show any tool tips.

Comment: Not to forget this one: [Showing the bibliographic entry in a popup when you hover over the citation key](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15356) (OOps, arleady linked by Torbjørn.)

Comment: Skim knows to do it AFAIK, but that's Mac only.

Comment: Necessary addition: In my comment above I was not fully right (or only right for “tooltip” in a strict meaning), see my answer [Tooltip that works with all pdf readers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160806).