# Is there any way to preview a bibliography inline?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

Take a look at the article at [this link](http://elifesciences.org/content/3/e04395): you will notice that mousing over hyperlinked citations generates a popup that previews the bibliographic entry corresponding to that citation. Is there a way to implement this in a tex-generated pdf?

Comment: Yes. Take a look at [cooltooltips](http://ctan.org/pkg/cooltooltips). If you need more help, post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) so that somebody can demonstrate.

Comment: See also [Showing the bibliographic entry in a popup when you hover over the citation key](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15356/35864).

Comment: Is there any way this question is different from the one I suggested above? If there is a difference, please explain it and make it more specific. If not, we might close this question as a duplicate.