# Is it possible to implement a citation style for BibLaTeX that is presenting the citation in a PDF annotation?

Tags: biblatex, citing, pdf, annotations

Citations are a thing that may be extremely useful for a newbie (at least I like seeing full paper author names and the paper title right where it is cited), and very annoying for experienced readers, who already know where ideas come from and for whom long citations interrupt their line of thought.

However, pdf supports a limited form of interactivity, called "sticky notes" or "annotations".

[image: A citation style mockup]

The annotation on the screenshot I created myself, manually. However, it came to me that this could be quite a user-friendly way of adding "collapsible" information to citations. For the experienced readers, the citations would be kept short (Batu, Fischer et al.), and new readers would be able to click at the annotation and get the full text of the citation, possibly with biber comments, and such.

How hard would be to implement such a package for latex?

Comment: You may want to look at the `pdfcomment` package. One caveat is that support for these annotations is not consistent across PDF readers. When I was looking at the documentation in my browser, I couldn't get any popups to work in Safari.

Comment: Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15356/35864.