# How to place a full citation in the abstract using BibTeX?

Tags: bibtex, citing

This question is similar to [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/815/how-to-instert-full-citation-instead-of-citation-key-list-of-authors-publicati) but not exactly the same.

I would like to include a reference in the abstract of a paper. This reference should be the full reference, not a key, and it should not interfere with the rest of the citations I make. The journal wants the references to be ordered numerically, and if I use `bibentry` the citation in the abstract gets `[1]` and so the first one in the paper is `[2]`...

any ideas how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Guess what, it is actually possible to do it!

The key is to define a new command, I called it `\nobibentry`, which will fetch the bibliography information of, say, `important-paper` to include in the abstract but *will not* add that entry to the bibliography so it won't get numbered just yet. In particular this means that entries won't be added until you issue the first `\cite` (which will appropriately get reference number `[1]`) and, for the whole thing to work, you should also add a citation to the `important-paper` somewhere in the body of the document.

An example is probably the best way to explain it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}

\newcommand{\ignore}[1]{}
\newcommand{\nobibentry}[1]{{\let\nocite\ignore\bibentry{#1}}}
% apsrev entries in the text need definitions of these commands
\newcommand{\bibfnamefont}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\bibnamefont}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}
\nobibliography*

In my abstract I want to talk about \nobibentry{important-paper}.

In the body of the text there is \cite{first-paper}, and also I talk
about \cite{another-paper}, but I should also not forget to cite
somewhere the \cite{important-paper}.

\bibliographystyle{apsrev}
\bibliography{your-bib-file}

\end{document}
```

And a short explanation. The `\bibentry` command (looking at the source in `bibentry.sty`) does essentially two things: (1) calls `\nocite` to introduce an entry into the list of references and (2) fetches the information from the list of references to typeset that information into the text. The problem is that calling `\nocite` at this point will also assign a reference number to this entry, and we don't want to do that just yet.

The `\nobibentry` uses `\let` to temporarily replace `\nocite` with a dummy `\ignore` command that simply discards its argument and does nothing, and then calls `\bibentry` to do the rest of the work. The extra pair of `{ .. }` in the definition of `\nobibentry` make sure that the redefinition of `\nocite` is only local to this small piece of code.

Comment: You don't, strictly speaking, need to cite `important-paper` in the body: there is a way to add an entry to a bibliography without citing it, isn't there?

Comment: Yes, but the point is that the entry *needs* to be added to the bibliography (so that `\bibentry` can find it) at some point or another (at which point it will get a number). You could `\nocite` it in the middle of the paper, but the sequence of reference numbers (in the body of the document) will appear to randomly skip a number for no apparent reason. Anyway, it would be strange not to cite the important paper if it was important enough to be mentioned in the abstract.

Comment: sweet! let me try it out. while you are at it, can you give a 2 line explanation of the `\let` command you used?

Comment: OH, so close! I can get it to work with `unsrt` but not with what I need wich is `apsrev` or `apsrev4-1`....it gives a strange error then.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it work with apsrev and natbib. If you're still having problems it would be best if you can edit your question with a complete and minimal example. So far I've just been trying to guess what does the code on your side looks like!

Comment: Thanks again. there was some sort of clash between the natbib and the revtex. but I got it to work without the natbib line, with documentclass{revtex4} (not 4-1), and \bibliographystyle{apsrev}. THANKS!

Comment: I had some trouble making this work. Seems like I first need to compile with "\nobibliography*" commented out, using revtex 4. Then I can uncomment "\nobibliography*" and get the correct result. Thanks!