# Include own reference list in CV

Tags: bibtex, citing

I have included papers I have authored in my main BibTeX library. How can I include full citations for these papers in a CV in LaTeX? I don't want a *citation* such as "Smith (2000)" anywhere in the CV, but rather the full citations of selected entries (my papers) inserted into the appropriate section of the CV, as a "list of my papers".

Comment: You can look at this answer: [How to place a full citation in the abstract using bibtex][1], it should apply to your question.




  [1]: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4297/how-to-place-a-full-citation-in-the-abstract-using-bibtex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `\nocite{*}` command. For a full "Bibliography" section you can do something like this:

```
\newpage
\addtocounter{section}{1}
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Title of the section (my papers?)}
\bibliographystyle{acm}
\bibliography{nameofthefile}

\nocite{*}
```

Comment: Thanks. I used `\nocite{myPaperA}`, `\nocite{myPaperB}` because `\nocite{*}` would include all the other references in the file.