# How can I insert a complete reference into abstract using BibTeX (elsarticle)

Tags: bibtex, citing

Following [[1]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4297/how-to-place-a-full-citation-in-the-abstract-using-bibtex)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{bibentry}

\newcommand{\ignore}[1]{}
\newcommand{\nobibentry}[1]{{\let\nocite\ignore\bibentry{#1}}}
% apsrev entries in the text need definitions of these commands
\newcommand{\bibfnamefont}[1]{#1}
\newcommand{\bibnamefont}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}
\nobibliography*

In my abstract I want to talk about \nobibentry{bil2012new}.

In the body of the text there is \cite{Smith:2013jd}, and also I talk
about \cite{maur2015}, but I should also not forget to cite
somewhere the \cite{bil2012new}.

\bibliographystyle{apsrev}
\bibliography{sample.bib}

\end{document}
```

I take, as desired,

> In my abstract I want to talk about N. Bil, Journal of XYZ 125, 4390
>   (2012). In the body of the text there is [[1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4297/how-to-place-a-full-citation-in-the-abstract-using-bibtex)], and also I talk about
>   [2], but I should also not forget to cite somewhere the [3].

However, if I chage the `documentclass` to

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
```

and the bibliography style to

```
\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names}
\bibliography{sample.bib}
```

(as requested)

I cannot take a similar output.

Thanks for any workaround.

Comment: If you are using the desired class and bib style the output should be according to them.

Comment: That means that I cannot bypass (at least for the abstract section) the bib style? From playing around I saw that the problem is not with the class `\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}` but with the bib style `model1-num-names`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `bibentry` works under the assumption that each entry in the `.bbl` file is followed by a blank line and, unfortunately, `model1-num-names.bst` doesn't respect this convention.

Modify a copy of `model1-num-names.bst`, say `model1-num-names+blank.bst` in the following way (line numbers added for reference) and place this modified copy in the working directory:

```
 91 FUNCTION {fin.entry}
 92 { add.period$
 93   write$
 94   newline$
 95 }
```

becomes

```
 91 FUNCTION {fin.entry}
 92 { add.period$
 93   write$
 94   newline$
 95   newline$
 96 }
```

Here's a working example:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{one,
  author={A. Uthor},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year={2010},
}
@article{two,
  author={A. Uthor},
  title={Title 2},
  journal={Journal},
  year={2011},
}
@article{three,
  author={W. Riter},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year={2012},
}
@article{four,
  author={S. C. I. Entist},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year={2013},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{bibentry}

\newcommand{\ignore}[1]{}
\newcommand{\nobibentry}[1]{{\let\nocite\ignore\bibentry{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\nobibliography*

\begin{frontmatter}
\title{Title}
\author{Me}

\begin{abstract}
In my abstract I want to talk about \nobibentry{one}.
\end{abstract}
\end{frontmatter}

In the body of the text there is \cite{three}, and also I talk
about \cite{two,four}, but I should also not forget to cite
somewhere the \cite{one}.

\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names+blank}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it possibly to drop the Title of the citation (only for the abstract)?

Comment: @dimitris Not that I know.

Comment: Thanks. I open a new question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288567/modify-the-argument-of-a-newcommand?lq=1 . So the best solution I want something like this is to write the item (in the abstract) on my own?

Comment: @dimitris Actually, now I know how to remove the title. ;-)

Comment: So, I look forward to seeing the answer:-)! In the meantime should I erase the new question and transfer the discussion here?

Comment: @dimitris No, it's a different problem, so better to have a separate followup question.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your time! I just add as a comment here, for the sake of completeness, that the original question  was indeed well answered:-)! In addition, the issue appeared in the comment above has an answer here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288567/removing-the-title-field-with-bibentry?lq=1 (where I opened a question about it).