# Removing the title field with \bibentry

Tags: elsarticle, bibentry

I have a question. Following the advice I got from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288534/how-can-i-insert-a-complete-reference-into-abstract-using-bibtex-elsarticle)

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{one,
  author={A. Uthor},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year={2010},
}
@article{two,
  author={A. Uthor},
  title={Title 2},
  journal={Journal},
  year={2011},
}
@article{three,
  author={W. Riter},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year={2012},
}
@article{four,
  author={S. C. I. Entist},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year={2013},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{bibentry}

\newcommand{\ignore}[1]{}
\newcommand{\nobibentry}[1]{{\let\nocite\ignore\bibentry{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\nobibliography*

\begin{frontmatter}
\title{Title}
\author{Me}

\begin{abstract}
In my abstract I want to talk about \nobibentry{one}.
\end{abstract}
\end{frontmatter}

In the body of the text there is \cite{three}, and also I talk
about \cite{two,four}, but I should also not forget to cite
somewhere the \cite{one}.

\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names+blank}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

will produce

[image]

How I should modify the structure

```
\newcommand{\ignore}[1]{}
    \newcommand{\nobibentry}[1]{{\let\nocite\ignore\bibentry{#1}}}
```

in order to modify the format of the item that appears in the Abstract according to my will?
For instance if I want to drop the appearance of the Title of the bib item?

Comment: I don't think there's a need to use the (unknown) `model1-num-names+blank` bibliography style. A similar output is achieved with `unsrt`.

Comment: Hi. The question is a sequel of the original question http://%20%20%20%20%20%20%20[1]:%20http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288534/how-can-i-insert-a-complete-reference-into-abstract-using-bibtex-elsarticle. In the reply I got, it was suggested to modify `model1-num-names.bst` (by adding an additional line).

Comment: @Werner, it's a slight modification of an elsevier .bst file. unsrt is for BibTeX I think, while the elsarticle class uses natbib I'm pretty sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a general solution, because it depends on how the `bst` writes out the `.bbl` file. In this particular case, adding

```
\makeatletter
\def\bibinfo@X@title#1,{\ignorespaces}
\makeatother
```

to the preamble makes `\bibentry` (and so also `\nobibentry`) into ignoring the title field.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@BOOK{simo2006computational,
  title={Computational inelasticity},
  author={Simo, Juan C and Hughes, Thomas JR},
  volume={7},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Springer Science \& Business Media},
 }
@article{one,
  author={A. Uthor},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year={2010},
}
@article{two,
  author={A. Uthor},
  title={Title 2},
  journal={Journal},
  year={2011},
}
@article{three,
  author={W. Riter},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year={2012},
}
@article{four,
  author={S. C. I. Entist},
  title={Title},
  journal={Journal},
  year={2013},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{bibentry}

\newcommand{\ignore}[1]{}
\newcommand{\nobibentry}[1]{{\let\nocite\ignore\bibentry{#1}}}

\makeatletter
\def\bibinfo@X@title#1,{\ignorespaces}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\nobibliography*

\begin{frontmatter}
\title{Title}
\author{Me}

\begin{abstract}\raggedright % just to show no extra spaces are added
In my abstract I want to talk about \nobibentry{simo2006computational}.
And also \nobibentry{one}.
\end{abstract}
\end{frontmatter}

In the body of the text there is \cite{three}, and also I talk
about \cite{two,four}, but I should also not forget to cite
somewhere the \cite{simo2006computational}. Also \cite{one}.

\bibliographystyle{model1-num-names+blank}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't know what's happening. When I run a simple sample file everything works fine. But I when I add the workaround in the article that I working it appears an error message `! Paragraph ended before \@tempa was complete.`

Comment: Can you add the bib entry causing the issue?

Comment: Of course! `@article{billon2012new,
  title={New constitutive modeling for time-dependent mechanical behavior of polymers close to glass transition: Fundamentals and experimental validation},
  author={Billon, No{\"e}lle},
  journal={Journal of Applied Polymer Science},
  volume={125},
  number={6},
  pages={4390--4401},
  year={2012},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}`

Comment: The weird thing is that the sample file I have created calls also the same `\bibliography` ! And it works as desired!

Comment: Sorry, but if I add the bib entry in my test file, I get no error.

Comment: The same holds true for the sample file I have created! The problem is the article I am working to. Strange indeed. Thank you very much once again.

Comment: I think the problem arises when there is a `@book` entry. Could you please test this? `@BOOK{simo2006computational,
  title={Computational inelasticity},
  author={Simo, Juan C and Hughes, Thomas JR},
  volume={7},
  year={2006},
  publisher={Springer Science \& Business Media}
}`

Comment: @dimitris I fixed it; however, I'm doubtful about a book cited without its title.