# How to place a custom citation in the abstract using BibTeX?

Tags: bibtex, citing

I would like to include a reference in the abstract of a paper. This reference should be something like (Author, year), not a key and not the full bibentry. Is there a way to do this?

This question is the same as [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4297/how-to-place-a-full-citation-in-the-abstract-using-bibtex) but the answer given is not exactly what I am looking for, since the whole bibentry is cited in the abstract.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{article,
  title={My article},
  author={Author McAuthorface},
  journal={Such and such},
  year={2017}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
I cite \cite{article} but I want to have (Mcauthorface, 2017)
\end{abstract}

Normal citations \cite{article} in the body of the text.

\bibliographystyle{acm}
\bibliography{\jobname.bib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)). It will be much easier when we see compilable code´(including a bib file) .

Comment: Most journals don't like citations in abstracts. However, if you do include one, it is better to make it complete - remember that the abstract is often used in isolation from the remainder of the document, including the list of references.

Comment: Added an example. @Michael That's why I want to cite (Author, year) which is more stand-alone than a number citation.

Comment: Sorry. I corrected the MWE to include a biblio

Comment: The citation should allow the reader to find the reference. If the reader only has access to the abstract but not the reference list, he won't be able to find "McAuthor, 2002".